# SOAP response. How to handle it?

Tags: php, laravel, soap

I have this function:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            self::setWsdl('http://000.000.00.00/SomeServices.asmx?WSDL');
            $this->service = InstanceSoapClient::init();
            $params = [
                'sGrupo' => "0".$request->sGrupo,
                'iCota' => $request->iCota,
                'iIdERP' => $request->iIdERP
            ];
            $response = $this->service->ROS_ExtratoContaCorrente($params);
            return view('layouts.extrato', compact('response'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

And the result using

```
dd($response);
```

I get:

```
{#198 ▼
  +"ExtratoContaCorrente": {#199 ▼
    +"NOME-CLIENTE": "JON DOE"
    +"CODIGO-GRUPO": "06275"
    +"NUMERO-COTA": 45
    +"NOME-LOGRADOURO": "STREET JUNIOR"
    +"NUMERO-LOGRADOURO": "519"
    +"BAIRRO": "PRESIDENTE ROOSEVELT"
    +"CIDADE": "UBERLANDIA"
    +"UF": "MG"
    +"CEP": "00000000"
    +"NUMERO-TELEFONE": "000 000000000"
    +"CODIGO-BEM": "6156"
    +"VALOR-BEM": 12000.0
    +"PERC-TOTAL-PAGO": 31.7396
    +"VALOR-QUITACAO": 10090.62
    +"PERC-TOAL-PAGAR": 0.5546
    +"PARCELAS-PAGAS": {#205 ▶}
    +"PARCELAS-PENDENTES": {#207 ▶}
    +"PROXIMA-ASSEMBLEIA": {#209 ▶}
    +"RESULT-ULTIMA-ASSEMB": {#210 ▶}
    +"CODIGO-RETORNO": 0
    +"DESCRICAO-RETORNO": ""
  }
}
```

How do I handle this data to render on a view? Right now I´m getting this error:
This is my view:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')

@endsection
@section('scripts')
<script>
    var vue = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            response: {!! $response !!}
        }
    })
</script>
```

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string (View: /Users/marcellopato/Sites/primorossicontemplado/resources/views/layouts/extrato.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

What is this response? An object, right? Why can I just compact as variable and send to a view?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Paste your blade.php template as well, please

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting on response is an object, for better use in blades try to cast it to array by doing the following:

```
$response = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);
```

or

```
$response = (array) $response;
```

Before passing to the view and:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    try 
    {

        self::setWsdl('http://000.000.00.00/SomeServices.asmx?WSDL');

        $this->service = InstanceSoapClient::init();

        $params        = [
            'sGrupo' => "0" . $request->sGrupo,
            'iCota'  => $request->iCota,
            'iIdERP' => $request->iIdERP,
        ];

        $response = $this->service->ROS_ExtratoContaCorrente($params);

        $response = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);

        return view('layouts.extrato', compact('response'));

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The given object has a `+` sign as a prefix foreach property which means that those properties are public properties, therfore casting it to json string and then parse json string to array will work.

> P.S if the object response has `-` signs on it (private properties) be aware that parsing
>   the object to `array` or `json_encode` `json_decode` will not work
>   properly.

Comment: @MarcelloPatto no it doesnt, the object that you have posted has clearly `+` so its public properties.

Comment: I meant ```-``` in the middle of the fields... you are right. It is a ```+```